# How to move the card view rest to the next card view in recyclerView in android

Tags: android, rest, android-recyclerview, move, cardview

I am creating an application kitchen display regarding restaurant automation. When creating the order it is added to the Recycler view can scroll horizontally. 
Item added to each Cardview in each order and if more item includes I need to the rest into the next column. image is shown it (Each order can't the scroll)
Are there any suggestions or method to do this?[image]

Comment: can you rephrase your question so it is more clear?

Comment: as the image shows order 1 has 8 items. but not enough space to displaying 8 items in one CardView. so I want to move the rest to next CardView.(Here user can,t scroll that's why I trying this way)

Answer (score 0):

There are `LayoutManager` for `RecyclerView` which handle the task of laying out the content in particular way.

For example, if you use `GridLayoutManager`, you'll be able to show the items in Grids, like the Gallery app.

In your case, you'll have to use `LinearLayoutManager`, with the horizontal orientation. You can do that as follows:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

Above LayoutManager will make the content to be laid out horizontally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already added a horizontal recycler view. the problem is not regarding that. Look the image you will be able to understand what I need. Order 1 has 8 items nor. but not enough to show all 8 items. the I need to add additional card view to the right side and add the rest item to the that cardView.

Comment: Okay so you want to create a new CardView with the new contents of the same order.

Comment: not the new content. I want to show the continuation  of the previous card

Comment: It'll take a lot of work to implement what you want to achieve. You'll have to check whether the current content is filling the window vertically, and if it is filling vertically, you need to create a new CardView in your ViewHolder and then set the remaining contents. It'll take long time to achieve what you want.

Comment: currently, I am using a recycler view in each card view to display items in each order. But the problem is the user must to scroll. It is difficult for my users

Comment: Yeah but it'd take a lot of time to code something like that. If the number of items won't be more, you can add an extra invisible/gone CardView, which will be shown when the current textviews are filled. But I think you're using RecyclerView inside a recyclerView to show the items in each card, so it'll be extra hard to code something like that.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your advice. I will go through your path and I will comment result to you.

Comment: Are you using RecyclerView inside the Cards that are shown? I'm asking about those "item1", "item2" in your mockup.