# Display list without scrolling

Tags: android, list, scroll, display

I want to display a list without scrolling vertically. if list height greater than the parent list must start from the next column. if column fit to the parent it must scroll horizontally. Image shows what I want. please help me to solve this problem[image]

Comment: Hello Madhura. Please consider providing us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as what you have done so far to achieve this result.

Comment: "Display list **without** scrolling"... "If column fit to the parent it **must scroll vertically**." So, the list should or shouldn't scroll?

Comment: sorry, sir, it is typing mistake. not vertically. I want to scroll list horizontally. the list is filling item 1, item 2 .... vertically. after it fit parent list must start next column top and fill top to bottom vertically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438584/how-to-move-the-card-view-rest-to-the-next-card-view-in-recyclerview-in-android/56438649?noredirect=1#comment99476056_56438649

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use a constraint layout. But the logic to break the list should be implemented by you when binding the adapter with the data and view. Recycler view will be a good container. I hope this sheds some light.

Comment: if I use a recycler view when item list height greater than the parent it scrolls automatically. I want to prevent it and I want to start list from next column top as image shows.